# JStree Search doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, jstree, jstree-search

My HTML has the scripts for `jstree.search.js` as well as `jstree.js` and I call `jstree()` like this:

```
tree = $('.jstree').jstree({
    core: {
        "check_callback" : true,
        "themes" : { "stripes" : true },
        },
      
    "plugins" : [
        "search", "state", "types"
      ]
    });
```

I can tell the `state` works, but the `search` simply doesn't seem to do anything. I was expecting for a search bar to appear, but there is none.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong: you have to include the search bar yourself.

```js
var $tree = $("#mytree");
var $input = $(
  "<input type='search' placeholder='Search' />"
);
$input.insertBefore($tree);
$input.on("keyup", function() {
  $tree.jstree(true).search($(this).val());
});
```

Enabling the plugin just allows to use the `.search` method.